# Android log fetching in my android application

Tags: java, android

I have a scenario where i need to read the data that is continuosly coming on logcat at interval of one second. So i have made a thread that calls this class method but I am ending up in exceptions like

```
Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

I have already added permission like

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

Code is

```
public class LogsUtil {  

    public static StringBuilder readLogs() {  
        StringBuilder logBuilder = new StringBuilder();  
        try {  

            String[] cmd = new String[] { "logcat | find \\ Keymaster" /*"logcat", "-v", "time", "ActivityManager:W", "Keymaster:D"*/ };
            //Process processClear = new ProcessBuilder().command("logcat -c").redirectErrorStream(true).start();

            //String cmd[] = new String[]{"logcat"};

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(/*"logcat -d"*/cmd);  

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(  
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));  

            String line;  
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                 Log.e(" ", ""+bufferedReader.readLine());
                logBuilder.append(line + "\n");  
            }  
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return logBuilder;  
    }  
}
```

Exact logs that needs to be read is 
[image]

How to get this same data printed ?

Comment: I think you should use `logcat -d` otherwise the process never stops

Comment: tried it, i am getting java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [logcat -d ] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Comment: is your device rooted?

Comment: Yes it is rooted one, i am working on engg build

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
String[] cmd = new String[] {"logcat", "-d", "Keymaster:V *:S" }
```

however if you need your own logs I recommend just to use your own logger

as `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />`

is too offensive for me.

You can use [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) to use specific local logger for your needs.
or common logger with visualizer form [the google examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicTransition/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/common/logger)

Comment: I tried the cmd you have asked and i am getting 06-24 12:00:48.304: E/(30012):  While true --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
06-24 12:00:49.281: E/(30012): null

Comment: Those logs that i need on my App UI aren't coming from my app instead it is coming from my Application's base library. I don't have access to listener which is producing that messages so i am doing an workaround right now

Comment: you can get anything that is coming from you app also the native log from other libs you use. However if you read logs from other apps you canot really do that on android >= 4.1 unless you have rooted device, development/engineering build, your application is in the system partition  or you messed up with the permissions or props on the device.
you can try to use reflection to hook to those logs. what is this keymaster lib you use?

Comment: Okay, this lib provides feature to postpone my display power off to defined seconds. My only task is to show this counter in UI nothing else.